# How to commit project's changes to git using ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant

I need to commit changes in eclipse project. I use the code below to do this:

```
<project name="my_library_project">
<macrodef name="git">
        <attribute name="command" />
        <attribute name="dir" default="" />
        <element name="args" optional="true" />
        <sequential>
            <echo message="git @{command}" />
            <exec executable="git" dir="@{dir}">
                <arg value="@{command}" />
                <args/>
            </exec>
        </sequential>
</macrodef>


<target name="Library">
    <echo>Hello Library!</echo>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/Library.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.library.test.Test"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>



<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/Library.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>


<target name="version" description="Commits all changes to version git">
        <input message="New version" addproperty="commit-message" />

        <echo message="Commiting all changes with message ${commit-message}" />

        <input file="Library.jar" addproperty="added-file" />

        <git command="add">
                    <args>
                        <arg value="${added-file}" />
                    </args>
        </git>

        <git command="commit">
            <args>
                <arg value="-am ${commit-message}" />
            </args>
        </git>
</target>
```

Every task have successfully completed except "version" task. Commit doesn't work. What's the problem? How should fix this code? 
This is the output:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build.xml
Library:
 [echo] Hello Library!
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build
compile:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build\classes
[javac] C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build.xml:26: warning: 'includeantruntime'         was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 20 source files to C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build\classes
[javac] warning: java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Comparable.class(java\lang:Comparable.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\String.class(java\lang:String.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\BufferedOutputStream.class(java\io:BufferedOutputStream.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\FileNotFoundException.class(java\io:FileNotFoundException.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\FileOutputStream.class(java\io:FileOutputStream.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\IOException.class(java\io:IOException.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\InputStream.class(java\io:InputStream.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\OutputStream.class(java\io:OutputStream.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\Closeable.class(java\io:Closeable.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\AutoCloseable.class(java\lang:AutoCloseable.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\Flushable.class(java\io:Flushable.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Override.class(java\lang:Override.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\Annotation.class(java\lang\annotation:Annotation.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\Target.class(java\lang\annotation:Target.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\ElementType.class(java\lang\annotation:ElementType.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\Retention.class(java\lang\annotation:Retention.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\RetentionPolicy.class(java\lang\annotation:RetentionPolicy.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Double.class(java\lang:Double.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Number.class(java\lang:Number.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\System.class(java\lang:System.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\PrintStream.class(java\io:PrintStream.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\FilterOutputStream.class(java\io:FilterOutputStream.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Exception.class(java\lang:Exception.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Throwable.class(java\lang:Throwable.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\FileDescriptor.class(java\io:FileDescriptor.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\File.class(java\io:File.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Error.class(java\lang:Error.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\RuntimeException.class(java\lang:RuntimeException.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\StringBuilder.class(java\lang:StringBuilder.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\AbstractStringBuilder.class(java\lang:AbstractStringBuilder.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\CharSequence.class(java\lang:CharSequence.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\StringBuffer.class(java\lang:StringBuffer.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\io\Serializable.class(java\io:Serializable.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Math.class(java\lang:Math.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] Note: C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\src\com\library\tree\RedBlackTree.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 35 warnings
jar:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build\jar
[jar] Building jar: C:\Users\sersem\git\Library\Library\build\jar\Library.jar
run:
 [java] Hello
 [java] Array is full
 [java] 2
 [java] 3
 [java] 4
 [java] 5
 [java] 6
 [java] 7
 [java] 8
 [java] 9
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and post some error messages as well?

Comment: But there is no error message. This is a thing. The unit "version" doesn't appear at all

Comment: What targets are you invoking? What's your command-line like?

Comment: I would like to make next commands `git add Library.jar` and `git commit -m "New version"`